# how to recover deleted files from disk image (plus more questions)?

Tags: mount, data-recovery

My mother was using a Windows machine and writing a document for a long days. Unfortunatelly, no backups of the document (Word).

Something happened during the boot process, she pressed a few times Enter and.. Windows recovered itself - it is like a new pc from shop..

Now is the question, how to recover this Word document..

so Far my plan is:

1) boot Linux from cd

2) connect usb disk (maybe I need to mount it too?)

3) lsblk for list how my internal disk is marked

4) using dd if=/dev/hda of=./part1.image (paths will be changed) to create a disk image from internal disk at external usb disk

5) then I can use another PC and try to recover files from disk image (win/Linux..)

so my question is:

is my approach correct?

how to mount external disk (or is there automount?)

what software I should use to recover files from disk image? (win or Linux, I have dualboot on my PC).

thanks a lot!

Comment: Give a try to `testdisk`